# Testfor specific items in player's offhand

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can I use `/testfor` to see if a player is holding a bow with the name "Crossbow" and lore "It is powerful" in his offhand?

Comment: thx it working!

Comment: If the answer works without issues tick the "tick" beside the arrows it will accept the question.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need:

```
/testfor @p {Inventory:[{Slot:-106b,id:minecraft:bow,tag:{display:{Name:"crossbow",Lore:["It is powerful"]}}}]}
```